# React version issue. Not able to upgrade version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I am not able to install `latest version of react`. Actually I installed a particlar version after appending @ , after that what ever I am doing it is not working. even I unistalled nodejs completely. still it is not working.

```
npm react --version
6.14.15
```

Then I ran this

```
npm install --save react@latest
```

After that version is still coming same.

```
 npm react --version
    6.14.15
```

After that I uninstalled react using below

```
npm uninstall -g create-react-app
```

I also did

```
   npm uninstall react
```

and then checked the version. it is still coming same.

I followed onw blog and tried below. still it dint work.

```
npm install react-scripts@4.0.0 react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0
```

and installed `react` again. still it is giving same `version`.
Could you please help me on the same.
Is there any to remove it completely from the system?

Comment: `create-react-app` is not `react`

Comment: try `npm install react-scripts@4.0.0 react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0` read here more
https://blog.bitsrc.io/upgrading-to-react-17-and-webpack-5-89eef0f41ae5

Comment: @ksav instead of putting question for close can you help me to understand?

Comment: @CodeBug  It dint work. I followed the same. but still it is giving same version.

Comment: are you using ubuntu? if so try with Sudo permission

Comment: I am using windows

Answer (score 2):

Let understand the diff between react and create react app.
React is a js library for creating user interfaces but and create react app is a cli tool that help us to create the files template for a react project and both are totally different npm packages.
[image]
The create react app doesn't depend on react so it doesn't install the required version of react.
If you want to upgrade your react library you have to install react

> npm i -g react@latest

Comment: Thank you Naveen. Actually even if I write npm uninstall react and if I check version it is still coming same. I mean it is not getting uninstalled.

Comment: Check this out, https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+uninstall+react+js

Comment: Remember that many packages you have instaled on your system may be dependent on react. Those packages might require react and if you want to remove react fully from your machine consider deleting everything.

Comment: is there any command to remove everything? even i uninstalled nodejs..but still the same issue

Comment: npm uninstall <name><br/>

// - removes it from dependencies in package.json aswell
npm uninstall <name> --save

// - removes it from devDependencies in package.json aswell
npm uninstall <name> --save-dev

// -  also removes it globally 
npm uninstall -g <name> --save